# Shoes for hiking and minor rock climbing in Australia?

Tags: rock-climbing, trekking, walking, shoes, australia

The reason I'm asking this is, I currently have a pair which I purchased from KMart for around $30 AUD, I've been using them for a while but I found they do not have proper griping on steep and uneven surfaces. I recently did a hard trail and found it very difficult with those shoes.

I'm looking for **shoes** that would be good for **bush walking** (*medium to hard*) and some minor **rock climbing** in **Australia**.

---

UPDATE:

I finally bought these:  Columbia Vapour Vent Hiking shoes from Adventure MegaStore. Hope to try them out soon :)

https://www.adventuremegastore.com.au/products/20783-columbia-mens-vapour-vent-hiking-shoes-black-white

Comment: Hi Nigel, welcome TGO. This might get closed as a shopping based question. I'll anyway share this question in the chat and see what others think. Feel free to pop in to the chat and get this information in case this question gets closed.

Comment: Hi @Ricketyship , how do I open chat ?

Comment: Click on the right top icon on your screen (i'm assuming it's a desktop version you are using). The one with three bars. There you should find a chat link next to the great outdoors title.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9HLFPWL

Comment: On hindsight, you might require a higher reputation to use the chat. So I'll go ahead and share the question.

Comment: Meanwhile here are a couple of questions to help you [1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/water-resistant-shoes-for-trekking-in-new-zealand) and [2](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/101/what-do-i-need-to-look-for-in-good-quality-hiking-boots?rq=1) these do not talk of brands. Brand based questions are out of scope here.

Comment: @Ricketyship thanks mate, you are very helpful .. cheers

Comment: probably you want to say "rock scrambling" instead of "rock climbing", (which requires more specific shoes that you don't use for hiking)

Comment: @endolith some grade 5 hiking tracks do involve a bit of actual rock climbing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For walking on rough terrain and scrambling in hot conditions I've found hiking shoes or approach shoes to work very well. That is after all what they're meant for. They're a bit tougher and heavier than trainers, and I suspect that the ones you had were essentially trainers styled like walking shoes (despite the label; I've had some like that from shoe shops).

I've had a couple of brands. The more expensive ones had exactly the same sole as a pair of hiking boots I also have, but cut lower at the ankle (KSB). I've had a few pairs, over the last 25 years, of a cheaper brand (HiTec)  that happens to fit me very well. The KSBs and most of the HiTecs have been waterproof/breathable. Brand is less important than fit and sole quality.

You probably need a proper outdoor shop, but the shoes you're sheet should be among the cheaper ones they sell. Most outdoor shops these days have a test ramp, a steep slope with climbing wall holds attached. Most will also be able to offer advice. Your budget seems perfectly sensible with UK pricing.

Comment: ok , I'll have a look at them... cheers mate